# Can someone please explain what k, a and r make sense into this mapM definition?i am a haskell newbie

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]

{-# INLINE mapM #-}

mapM f as = foldr k (return []) as

            where

              k a r = do { x <- f a; xs <- r; return (x:xs) }
```

Comment: `a` is a element of the `[a]` list, `r` is the *remaining*-computation ... don't know what else I could say ... you understand how `foldr` works?

Comment: You should be using `traverse` instead of `mapM` anyway. It's more general and can sometimes be more efficient too (when `mapM` is more efficient, someone's probably messed up).

Answer (score 1):

The type of `foldr` is:

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> c -> c) -> c -> t a -> c
```

in this case `t = []` so it is:

```
foldr :: (a -> c -> c) -> c -> [a] -> c
```

in the invocation of `foldr`:

```
foldr k (return []) as
```

`return []` has type `m [b]` and `as` has type `[a]` so `k` should have type

```
k :: a -> m [b] -> m [b]
```

so in the definition of `k`:

```
k a r = do { x <- f a; xs <- r; return (x:xs) }
```

`a` has type `a` and `r` has type `m [b]`.

Answer (score 1):

"k" is a function defined inside "mapM" and so, only mapM can see that.

In their definition "k" receives two parameters named "a" and "r".

Because "k" function is being used in "foldr" it's expected that these two parameters play the next role:

```
"a" - will be every element inside the list "as"
"r" - at first it will be "return []", but next time "r" will take 
      the result of "k" applied to "a" and "r" (like an accumulator)
```